# How Ruby on Rails work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I programmed in php. And when you use some framework, then, as far as php is intepreter, all the framework loads every request. But not rails, though, ruby is interperter too... So, how does it work

Comment: I mean, how is it managed... Does it load its enviroment (ActiveRecord, ActiveSupport etc) for every request like in php?

Comment: -1 classic write-me-a-book question

Comment: It has nothing to do with the interpreter. It's about the way the framework communicate with the web server. For example [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) applications dont do a reload on every request, even PHP ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Rails as the framework caches all loaded modules, class and libraries on the first several requests (it's not on the first request only since it also has lazy load for above things).

But by default under development mode, all app modules (mvc) are reloaded on each request. Libraries (plugins, gems, etc) are not reloaded.

Comment: I know that. I just want to know, how it does that. Ruby is interpreter, so it has to finish after the program executes

Comment: It doesn't finish after each request, it awaits new requests. Think it as a daemon running a loop. But I know this is not what you want. Luckily both ruby and rails and tons of gems rails depends on are open source so you could take a look the implementation if you really want to and are willing to take the time.

Comment: There's nothing that says an interpreted language has to stop at any point. Ruby on Rails usually runs as at least one persistent process and will service many requests over its lifespan. PHP is deliberately cleaned out between requests and starts from scratch each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hugely wide open and too large to really answer effectively. This is a good place: [RoR Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). If after reading that you have more specific and directed questions bring them back and we'll try our best to help you...